# In Pandas, astype() just plain doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's what I say:

```
df["rating"] = df["rating"].astype(str, errors='ignore')
df.dtypes
```

Here's what it prints:

```
name                object
platform            object
year_of_release      int64
genre               object
na_sales           float64
eu_sales           float64
jp_sales           float64
other_sales        float64
critic_score       float64
user_score         float64
rating              object
total_sales        float64
reviewed              bool
dtype: object
```

As you can see, rating is still an object and not a string. Why is it so?

Comment: pandas does not use string as a type for pandas.Series.
Instead it uses object, which can be treated as a string in most cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Pandas 1.0, the extension types, `StringDtype` was introduced. Per [Work with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html) docs:

> There are two ways to store text data in pandas:
>
> 1. `object` -dtype NumPy array.
> 2. `StringDtype` extension type.
>
> We recommend using `StringDtype` to store text data.
>
> Prior to pandas 1.0, object `dtype` was the only option.

Currently, with `astype(str)`, you are rendering an `object` type which can contain *any* mix of types including numbers and strings. However, since Pandas 1.0+, you can now use a dedicated string type:

```py
df["rating"] = df["rating"].astype("string")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command

```
df["rating"]=df["rating"].apply(obj).astype('str')
```